# É possivel modificar algum campo antes de realizar uma busca? (PHP MYSQL)

Tags: php, mysql

> "SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE conteudo LIKE '%$pesquisa%'"

É possível modificar os valores da coluna 'conteudo' antes da busca ser realizada?

**Exemplo:**

> "SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE strip_tags(conteudo) LIKE '%$pesquisa%'"

É possível realizar algo semelhante?

Tenho um conteúdo que está todo com codificação e tags HTML, gostaria de filtra-lo e deixar apenas o texto durante a busca.

**Exemplo de Conteúdo:**

```html
   <p><b>A</b> hist&oacute;ria da vida.</p>
```

Se a $pesquisa for 'história' por exemplo, ele não irá encontrar nenhum resultado.

Comment: Possível é, mas convém você explicar melhor o que está fazendo, para ter uma resposta mais adequada. Você quer dar um `strip_tags` no campo em vez de dar o `strip_tags` no que vai ser pesquisado? Claro que o MySQL não vai entender comandos de PHP, mas dependendo do que você quer, dá pra fazer no PHP antes da _query_, ou trocando as funções do PHP por similares do MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vejo três possibilidades para seu problema.

- Utilizar a função `REPLACE`, o que deixaria a busca extremamente lenta, devido a quantidade de substituições que terá que fazer por registro;
- Gravar em outro campo da tabela o texto sem HTML, porem irá consumir muito espaço muito espaço em disco gravando dados duplicados;
- Recorrer a algoritmos de Recuperação de informação.

Existem vários tipos de algoritmos de recuperação de informação, indo do mais simples a muito complexos como a do Google. O que vou apresentar aqui é muito usado em SEO.

Porem aqui está uma explicação de como montar um algoritmo simples desses e melhorar as buscas.

O processo básico para recuperação de informação consiste em tratar o texto que será guardado, extraindo informações relevantes que irão auxiliar na consulta e ranqueamento dos resultados. Sendo eles os tratamentos de texto:

- **Tokenização**: Separar todas as palavras do texto;
- **Normalização**: Transformar em minúsculas todas as letras, retirar simbolos e acentos;
- **Stopwords**: Remoção de paravras irrelevantes para buscas como "a", "e", "o" "de", "para", "por", etc;
- **Stemming**: Converter todas as palavras para a raiz gramatical. Não iremos trabalhar esta parte por precisar de um dicionário bem complexo.

Vamos usar a string de exemplo:

```
$string = '&Aacute; <strong>Oi</strong> aqui é um teste!!     \n Faça tudo para tirar simbolos e acentos deste teste.';
```

```
/**
 * Removendo o HTML.
 */
$clean = html_entity_decode($string);
$clean = strip_tags($clean);

/**
 * Removendo acendos e símbolos.
 */
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pt_BR.UTF8');

// Remove espaços e quebra de linha.
$clean = trim($string);
$clean = preg_replace('/\s(?=\s)/', '', $clean);
$clean = preg_replace('/[\n\r\t]/', ' ', $clean);

// Remove acentos. Atenção para a função iconv que deve estar instalada.
$clean = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $string);

// Remove tudo que não for letra ou número.
$clean = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\/_| -]/", '', $clean);

// transforma tudo em minúsculo.
$string = strtolower(trim($clean, '-'));

/**
 * Removendo stopwords.
 */
// Criando dicionário de stopwords.
$stopwords = array(
    'a', 'agora', 'ainda', 'ali', 'alguem', 'algum', 'alguma', 'algumas',
    'alguns', 'ampla', 'amplas', 'amplo', 'amplos', 'ante', 'antes', 'ao',
    'aos', 'apos', 'aquela', 'aquelas', 'aquele', 'aqueles', 'aqui', 'aquilo',
    'as', 'ate', 'atraves', 'cada', 'coisa', 'coisas', 'com', 'como', 'contra',
    'contudo', 'da', 'daquele', 'daqueles', 'das', 'de', 'dela', 'delas', 'dele',
    'deles', 'depois', 'dessa', 'dessas', 'desse', 'desses', 'desta',
    'destas', 'deste', 'deste', 'destes', 'deve', 'devem', 'devendo',
    'dever', 'devera', 'deverao', 'deveria', 'deveriam', 'devia', 'deviam',
    'disse', 'disso', 'disto', 'dito', 'diz', 'dizem', 'do', 'dos', 'e',
    'ela', 'elas', 'ele', 'eles', 'em', 'enquanto', 'entre', 'era', 'essa',
    'essas', 'esse', 'esses', 'esta', 'esta', 'estamos', 'estao', 'estas',
    'estava', 'estavam', 'estavamos', 'este', 'estes', 'estou', 'eu',
    'fazendo', 'fazer', 'feita', 'feitas', 'feito', 'feitos', 'foi', 'for',
    'foram', 'fosse', 'fossem', 'grande', 'grandes', 'ha', 'isso', 'isto',
    'ja', 'la', 'lhe', 'lhes', 'lo', 'mas', 'me', 'mesma', 'mesmas',
    'mesmo', 'mesmos', 'meu', 'meus', 'minha', 'minhas', 'muita', 'muitas',
    'muito', 'muitos', 'na', 'nao', 'nas', 'nem', 'nenhum', 'nessa',
    'nessas', 'nesta', 'nestas', 'ninguem', 'no', 'nos', 'nos', 'nossa',
    'nossas', 'nosso', 'nossos', 'num', 'numa', 'nunca', 'o', 'os', 'ou',
    'outra', 'outras', 'outro', 'outros', 'para', 'pela', 'pelas', 'pelo',
    'pelos', 'pequena', 'pequenas', 'pequeno', 'pequenos', 'per', 'perante',
    'pode', 'pude', 'podendo', 'poder', 'poderia', 'poderiam', 'podia',
    'podiam', 'pois', 'por', 'porem', 'porque', 'posso', 'pouca', 'poucas',
    'pouco', 'poucos', 'primeiro', 'primeiros', 'propria', 'proprias',
    'proprio', 'proprios', 'quais', 'qual', 'quando', 'quanto', 'quantos',
    'que', 'quem', 'sao', 'se', 'seja', 'sejam', 'sem', 'sempre', 'sendo',
    'sera', 'serao', 'seu', 'seus', 'si', 'sido', 'so', 'sob', 'sobre',
    'sua', 'suas', 'talvez', 'tambem', 'tampouco', 'te', 'tem', 'tendo',
    'tenha', 'ter', 'teu', 'teus', 'ti', 'tido', 'tinha', 'tinham', 'toda',
    'todas', 'todavia', 'todo', 'todos', 'tu', 'tua', 'tuas', 'tudo',
    'ultima', 'ultimas', 'ultimo', 'ultimos', 'um', 'uma', 'umas', 'uns',
    'vendo', 'ver', 'vez', 'vindo', 'vir', 'vos', 'vos'
);
$string = preg_replace('/\b(' . implode('|', $stopwords) . ')\b/', '', $string);

/**
 * Obtendo os Tokens já com a quantidade de repetição das palavras.
 */
$tokens = explode(' ', $string);
//$tokens = array_count_values($string);
// Agrupa todas as palavras repetidas.
// Caso queira partir para um algoritmo mais complexo de indexação, utilize
// a função 'array_count_values' no lugar de 'array_flip', assim vc terá as
// palavras e a quantidade que cada uma repete.
// $tokens = array_count_values($string);
$tokens = array_flip($string);

// Tratando para o armazenamento
$keywords = join(',', $tokens);
```

Pronto agora precisamos guardar isto no banco de dados para facilitar a busca.
Para isso crie em sua tabela um campo chamado `keywords`, e antes de inserir
o conteúdo, execute o algoritmo acima.

Em suas buscas monte um código da seguinte maneira:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM textos WHERE keywords LIKE "%:keywords%"';
$keywords = explode(',', $string);
$keywords = join('%', $string);
$stmt->execute( array( ':keywords' => $keywords ) );
$result = $res->fetchAll();
```

Caso sua tabela seja MyISAM ficará melhor ainda.

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM textos WHERE MATCH(keywords) AGAINST(":keywords" IN BOOLEAN MODE)';
$stmt->execute( array( ':keywords' => $keywords ) );
$result = $res->fetchAll();
```

O uso de `IN BOOLEAN MODE` te permite especificar coisas do tipo "+teste tirar simbolo" que irá encontrar resultados com obrigatóriamente a palavra teste e as outras caso tenha. Veja os links abaixo para saber mais.

- http://www.vionblog.com/mysql-full-text-search-with-multiple-words/
- http://www.designersgate.com/blogs/handling-keyword-search-phpmysql/

Agora para os textos já existentes, faça um script que percorra todos os
registros e faça o tratamento acima.

Answer (score 0):

Sim, você pode utilizar a função [REPLACE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace), segue um exemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE REPLACE(conteudo, 'procura', 'substitui') LIKE '%$pesquisa%'
```

Espero que ajude

Answer (score 0):

Para algo parecido ao que deseja, o MYSQL suporta um tipo de pesquisa chamado de FULL TEXT SEARCH que faz uma pesquisa bem diferente da comparação comum.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-query-expansion.html

Com ela eh possível fazer algumas pesquisas com conteúdo variável onde o resultado se da pela porcentagem que o valor pesquisado se encontra nas colunas pesquisadas.